# MongoDB to BigQuery Dataflow job does not transfer all the data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been trying to transfer some data from MongoDB (a few MongoDB collections) to BigQuery through Pubsub in between. I created a Pubsub topic with a default subscription. I did not make any changes to the default subscription. I have a Python script that publishes the messages to Pubsub and a dataflow job that takes those messages and writes to BigQuery. I am creating the DataFlow job from Template (MongoDB to BQ CDC).
But when the Script finishes publishing the messages I see only a portion of the data got transferred and it transfers data randomly not orderly. If I run my script again I see another portion of the data got transferred this time and that might be different from the last time.
I am fairly new to this. Any pointers what might be going wrong?